# In Scala, is there an easy way to convert a case class into a tuple?

Tags: scala, tuples, case-class

Is there an easy way to convert a case class into a tuple?

I can, of course, easily write boilerplate code to do this, but I mean without the boilerplate.

What I'm really after is a way to easily make a case class lexicographically Ordered. I can achieve the goal for tuples by importing scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._, and voila, my tuples have an Ordering defined for them. But the implicits in scala.math.Ordering don't work for case classes in general.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

How about calling `unapply().get` in the companion object?

```
case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Int)

val (str, in) = Foo.unapply(Foo("test", 123)).get
// str: String = test
// in: Int = 123
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, in the REPL 2.9.0-1 I had to remove the () to "get"

Comment: Cool, that worked! With your suggestion I was able to get my case class Ordered like so: `val thisTuple: Ordered[(String, Int)] = Foo.unapply(this).get; val thatTuple = Foo.unapply(that).get; thisTuple compare thatTuple`.

That's not the prettiest thing in the world, so I'm still open to suggestions, but your answer surely gets the job done. Thanks!

Comment: This is quite cumbersome, not really an improvement over just boilerplating it.

Comment: You can't call `get()` in new scala versions, only `get`

Comment: Calling `.get` on the `Option` returned from .`unapply` is a code smell; i.e. bad practice. So, this answer is fairly sketchy. For a better answer, see this answer where the `.get` is safely and exhaustively handled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43310062/501113

Comment: The method contract of `.unapply` here guarantees that the `Option` will be a `Some` - in other cases it will be `None`. In other cases we might not know, but here we do, and won't have to validate this contract at runtime. Hence it's fine to call `.get`.

Answer (score 6):

[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) will do this for you.

```
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.syntax.std.product._

  case class Fnord(a: Int, b: String)

  List(Fnord(1, "z - last"), Fnord(1, "a - first")).sortBy(_.productElements.tupled)
```

Gets

```
res0: List[Fnord] = List(Fnord(1,a - first), Fnord(1,z - last))
```

productElements turns a case class into a Shapeless HList:

```
scala> Fnord(1, "z - last").productElements
res1: Int :: String :: shapeless.HNil = 1 :: z - last :: HNil
```

And HLists are converted to tuples with #tupled:

```
scala> Fnord(1, "z - last").productElements.tupled
res2: (Int, String) = (1,z - last)
```

Performance is likely to be horrible, since you're constantly converting.  You'd probably convert everything to the tupled form, sort that, then convert it back using something like `(Fnord.apply _).tupled`.

Answer (score 6):

Scala 3 has first class support for conversions between case classes and tuples:

```
scala> case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Int)
// defined case class Foo

scala> Tuple.fromProductTyped(Foo("a string", 1))
val res0: (String, Int) = (a string,1)

scala> summon[deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[Foo]].fromProduct(res0)
val res1: deriving.Mirror.ProductOf[Foo]#MirroredMonoType = Foo(a string,1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Came across this old thread while attempting to do this same thing. I eventually settled on this solution:

```
case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Int)

val testFoo = Foo("a string", 1)

val (str, in) = testFoo match { case Foo(f, b) => (f, b) }
```

Comment: I like this approach because I can avoid calling `.get` on the `Option` returned from `unapply`. I'm wondering why a case class doesn't have a method called `.toTuple` which returns the literal tuple, not in an `Option`; i.e what you are literally doing. For .`unapply` on a case class instance, the result will always be a 'Some' forcing me to call `.get` which is a code smell.

Comment: *"I can, of course, easily write boilerplate code to do this, but I mean without the boilerplate"*

- this answer does not meet that criteria, and in fact is longer than the simple `(testFoo.foo, testFoo.bar)`

Answer (score 3):

You might try extending the `ProductN` trait, for N=1-22, which `TupleN` extends. It will give you  a lot of Tuple semantics, like the `_1`, `_2`, etc. methods. Depending on you how you use your types, this might be sufficient without creating an actual Tuple.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this approach to work for me. I want my case class either to be lexicographically Ordered or to have a lexicographical Ordering, without having to write lots of boilerplate. Extending ProductN doesn't seem to work with the implicits in scala.math.Ordering that allow one to easily give tuples a lexicographic ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a general solution, but sadly the most elegant way for me is to add the `toTuple` inside the case class itself. At least before we migrate to Scala 3.

```scala
case class Foo(foo: String, bar: Int) {
  val toTuple: (foo, bar) = (foo, bar)
}
```