# Scala extreme destructuring?

Tags: scala, macros, destructuring

I have this line of code, where I use the most idiomatic way I know, for destructuring an object coming back from a function:

```
val (a, b) = foo match { case MyObjectType(a, b) => (a, b) }
```

The object's prototype being:

```
case class MyObjectType(Type1: SomeType1, Type2: SomeType2)
```

Of course I could otherwise:

```
val returnType = foo
val (a, b) = (returnType.a, returnType.b)
```

But the latter is rather a different form of stating the same problem - this is really not elegant. Could a Scala macro come to the rescue to provide a succinct idiom? perhaps allowing syntax like either:

```
val (a, b) = foo deconstruct { MyObjectType(a, b) => (a, b) } // merely more shorthand, like scala allows e.g. within a map block

val (a, b) = tuplize(foo)                                     // assumes tuplize can iterate the vals of MyObjectType

tupleResult(a, b) = foo                                       // radical macro api exploring the limits of macro safety...

tupledVars(foo)                                               // macro extreme
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kind of an answer, but that does not give you a tuple. Do you know that this works:

`val MyObjectType(a,b) = foo`

Also if you are destructuring varargs T* you can do Code such as follows:

```
val Array(first, second, _*) = Array(1,2,3,4)
val Array(fst, snd, _*) = Array(1,2)
```

If you want tuples directly see [In Scala, is there an easy way to convert a case class into a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087958/in-scala-is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-case-class-into-a-tuple)

Comment: Thanks this is better than a tuple, I was thinking tuple just because I thought the solution would go through one, but this gets the job done! I wonder how that works under the hood though... 

the referenced answer had really poor answers on it BTW. This solution is much more useful, yet I wonder why it works, if you'd care to elabroate.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to explore generic programming with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
scala> import shapeless._, syntax.std.product._, syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.product._
import syntax.std.tuple._

scala> case class Foo(i: Int, s: String, b: Boolean)
defined class Foo

scala> val foo = Foo(1, "foo", true)
foo: Foo = Foo(1,foo,true)
```

Now with the help of `Generic` we can convert `Foo` to `HList` and back

```
scala> Generic[Foo].to(foo)
res0: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Boolean,shapeless.HNil]]] = 1 :: foo :: true :: HNil

scala> Generic[Foo].from(res0)
res1: Foo = Foo(1,foo,true)
```

Or you can use nice syntactic sugar provided by `syntax.std.product`

```
scala> foo.toHList
res2: this.Repr = 1 :: foo :: true :: HNil

scala> foo.toTuple
res3: (Int, String, Boolean) = (1,foo,true)
```

See [feature overview](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) and [examples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I keep an arm's length from mixing in shapeless for now, until I get better at understanding what it does under the hood and in particular the performance impacts of its idioms