# How to do generic tuple -> case class conversion in Scala?

Tags: scala

Let's say someone provided a function:

```
def getTupleData[T](source: String): List[T] = {
  // ...
}
```

I need to write a function which takes a case class `C` as the type parameter and return `List[C]` with the help of the above function. Here is what I have got so far:

```
def getCaseClassData[C](source: String): List[C] = {
  // Somehow get T from C.
  // For example, if C is case class MyCaseClass(a: Int, b: Long), then T is (Int, Long)
  // How to get T?      

  getTupleData[T](source) map { tuple: T =>
    // Somehow convert tuple into a case class instance with the case class type parameter
    // C.tupled(tuple) ??  Type parameter cannot be used like this. :(
  }
}
```

More specifically, it seems to me I'm asking two questions here:

1. How to explicitly obtain the type of the tuple from a type parameter which represents a case class so that it can be used as a type parameter?
2. How to create a case class instance from a tuple instance without knowing the actual name of the case class but only a type parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087958/in-scala-is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-case-class-into-a-tuple

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: 1) I'm talking about generics here, totally different story as I see it, and 2) the question you referred to is converting from case class to tuple.

Comment: What is denoted by `T` type?

Comment: I intended it to be the type of the corresponding tuple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't find any reasonably simple or direct way to do it. If you' re ready for the more involved solutions, bear with me.

Every case class has an `apply` method in its companion object, which instantiates the class. By calling `tupled` on this method (after eta-expansion), you'll get a function that takes a tuple and creates the corresponding case class instance.

Now of course the problem is that the every case class's `apply` has a different signature. We can get around this by introducing a type class representing a case class factory, and provide instances of this type class through a macro (which will just delegate to the case class's `apply` method).

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

trait CaseClassFactory[C,T]{
  type Class = C
  type Tuple = T
  def apply(t: Tuple): C
}

object CaseClassFactory {
  implicit def factory1[C,T]: CaseClassFactory[C,T] = macro factoryImpl[C,T]
  implicit def factory2[C]: CaseClassFactory[C,_] = macro factoryImpl[C,Nothing]
  def apply[C,T]: CaseClassFactory[C,T] = macro factoryImpl[C,T]
  def apply[C]: CaseClassFactory[C,_] = macro factoryImpl[C,Nothing]

  def factoryImpl[C:c.WeakTypeTag,T:c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    val C = weakTypeOf[C]
    val companion = C.typeSymbol.companion match {
      case NoSymbol => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Instance of $C has no companion object")
      case sym      => sym
    }
    val tupledTree = c.typecheck(q"""($companion.apply _).tupled""")
    val T = tupledTree.tpe match {
      case TypeRef(_, _, List(argTpe, _)) => argTpe
      case t => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Expecting type constructor (Function1) for $C.tupled, but got $t: ${t.getClass}, ${t.getClass.getInterfaces.mkString(",")}")
    }
    if (! (c.weakTypeOf[T] <:< T)) {
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Incompatible tuple type ${c.weakTypeOf[T]}: not a sub type of $T")
    }
    q"""
    new CaseClassFactory[$C,$T] {
      private[this] val tupled = ($companion.apply _).tupled
      def apply(t: Tuple): $C = tupled(t)
    }
    """
  }
}
```

With it you can do something like this:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
defined class Person

scala> val f = CaseClassFactory[Person]
f: CaseClassFactory[Person]{type Tuple = (String, Long)} = $anon$1@63adb42c

scala> val x: f.Tuple = ("aze", 123)
x: f.Tuple = (aze,123)

scala> implicitly[f.Tuple =:= (String, Long)]
res3: =:=[f.Tuple,(String, Long)] = <function1>

scala> f(("aze", 123))
res4: Person = Person(aze,123)
```

But more importantly, you can require an instance of `CaseClassFactory` as an implicit parameter, allowing to generically instantiate your case classes. You can then do something like:

```
scala> implicit class TupleToCaseClassOps[T](val t: T) extends AnyVal {
     |   def toCaseClass[C](implicit f: CaseClassFactory[C,T]): C = {
     |     f(t)
     |   }
     | }
defined class TupleToCaseClassOps

scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
defined class Person

scala> ("john", 21).toCaseClass[Person]
res5: Person = Person(john,21)
```

Pretty neat. Armed with this type class, `getCaseClassData` then becomes:

```
def getCaseClassData[C](source: String)(implicit f: CaseClassFactory[C,_]): List[C] = {
  getTupleData[f.Tuple](source) map { tuple: f.Tuple =>
    f(tuple)
  }
}
```