# How do I put a case class in an rdd and have it act like a tuple(pair)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, rdd

Say for example, I have a simple case class

```
case class Foo(k:String, v1:String, v2:String)
```

Can I get spark to recognise this as a tuple for the purposes of something like this, without converting to a tuple in, say a map or keyBy step.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Foo("k", "v1", "v2")))
// Swap values
rdd.mapValues(v => (v._2, v._1))
```

I don't even care if it looses the original case class after such an operation. I've tried the following with no luck. I'm fairly new to Scala, am I missing something?

```
case class Foo(k:String, v1:String, v2:String)
  extends Tuple2[String, (String, String)](k, (v1, v2))
```

edit: In the above snippet the case class extends Tuple2, this does not produce the desired effect that the RDD class and functions do not treat it like a tuple and allow PairRDDFunctions, such as mapValues, values, reduceByKey, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, is there an easy way to convert a case class into a tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087958/in-scala-is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-case-class-into-a-tuple)

Comment: No, I'm aware of that.
When given a tuple spark normally allows extra operations such as mapValues, but this extension of tuple doesn't get those

Comment: So I guess I'm trying to figure out what you actually want to do here. Are you saying that you have a case class and you want to perform tuple-like functions on that case class without actually turning it into a tuple?

Comment: Yes, the case class extends tuple, but for some reason in spark it doesn't allow me access to the PairRDDFunctions

Comment: Problem is that case classes are not designed for inheritance in the first place and case-to-case inheritance is not allowed. Could you explain what is the point of all of that if you _don't even care if it looses the original case class after such an operation_?

Comment: I think my point is if I pass a case class which extends Tuple2 to an RDD why does it not behave the same as passing a Tuple2 directly?

Comment: How are you getting that to compile in the first place?  Tuple2 is a case class, and so it can't be extended by another case class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending `TupleN` isn't a good idea for a number of reasons, with one of the best being the fact that it's deprecated, and on 2.11 it's not even possible to extend `TupleN` with a case class. Even if you make your `Foo` a non-case class, defining it on 2.11 with `-deprecation` will show you this: "warning: inheritance from class Tuple2 in package scala is deprecated: Tuples will be made final in a future version.".

If what you care about is convenience of use and you don't mind the (almost certainly negligible) overhead of the conversion to a tuple, you can enrich a `RDD[Foo]` with the syntax provided by `PairRDDFunctions` with a conversion like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.{ PairRDDFunctions, RDD }

case class Foo(k: String, v1: String, v2: String)

implicit def fooToPairRDDFunctions[K, V]
  (rdd: RDD[Foo]): PairRDDFunctions[String, (String, String)] =
    new PairRDDFunctions(
      rdd.map {
        case Foo(k, v1, v2) => k -> (v1, v2)
      }
    )
```

And then:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Foo("a", "b", "c"), Foo("d", "e", "f")))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Foo] = ParallelCollectionRDD[6] at parallelize at <console>:34

scala> rdd.mapValues(_._1).first
res0: (String, String) = (a,b)
```

The reason your version with `Foo` extending `Tuple2[String, (String, String)]` doesn't work is that `RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions` targets an `RDD[Tuple2[K, V]]` and `RDD` isn't covariant in its type parameter, so an `RDD[Foo]` isn't a `RDD[Tuple2[K, V]]`. A simpler example might make this clearer:

```
case class Box[A](a: A)

class Foo(k: String, v: String) extends Tuple2[String, String](k, v)

class PairBoxFunctions(box: Box[(String, String)]) {
  def pairValue: String = box.a._2
}

implicit def toPairBoxFunctions(box: Box[(String, String)]): PairBoxFunctions =
  new PairBoxFunctions(box)
```

And then:

```
scala> Box(("a", "b")).pairValue
res0: String = b

scala> Box(new Foo("a", "b")).pairValue
<console>:16: error: value pairValue is not a member of Box[Foo]
       Box(new Foo("a", "b")).pairValue
                              ^
```

But if you make `Box` covariant…

```
case class Box[+A](a: A)

class Foo(k: String, v: String) extends Tuple2[String, String](k, v)

class PairBoxFunctions(box: Box[(String, String)]) {
  def pairValue: String = box.a._2
}

implicit def toPairBoxFunctions(box: Box[(String, String)]): PairBoxFunctions =
  new PairBoxFunctions(box)
```

…everything's fine:

```
scala> Box(("a", "b")).pairValue
res0: String = b

scala> Box(new Foo("a", "b")).pairValue
res1: String = b
```

You can't make `RDD` covariant, though, so defining your own implicit conversion to add the syntax is your best bet. Personally I'd probably choose to do the conversion explicitly, but this is a relatively un-horrible use of implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question right, but let say you have a case class

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class DataFormat(id: Int, name: String, value: Double)
val data: Seq[(Int, String, Double)] = Seq(
   (1, "Joe", 0.1),
   (2, "Mike", 0.3)
)
val rdd: RDD[DataFormat] = (
    sc.parallelize(data).map(x=>DataFormat(x._1, x._2, x._3))
)

// Print all data
rdd.foreach(println)

// Print only names
rdd.map(x=>x.name).foreach(println)
```